# Bipartite graph projections, with threshold

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, space-complexity, network-modeling, bipartite-graphs

Let $G=(\top,\bot,E)$ be a *bipartite* graph: $E\subseteq \top\times\bot$.

The **projections** $G_\bot = (\bot,E_\bot)$ and $G_\top = (\top,E_\top)$ of $G$ are defined as follows: two vertices are linked together if they have a common neighbor in $G$.

**Weighted projections** are defined by adding the following weight function: $\omega(u,v)$ is the number of common neighbors of $u$ and $v$ in $G$.

For any $k$, the **$k$-projections** $G^k_\bot = (\bot,E^k_\bot)$ and $G^k_\top = (\top,E^k_\top)$ are defined as follows: two vertices are linked together if they have at least $k$ common neighbors in $G$.

Assume that both $G$, $G_{\bot}$, and $G_{\top}$ are **sparse**.

**Questions:**

- What is the (time and space) complexity of building $G_\bot$ and $G_\top$?
- Is it possible to build their weighted version with same complexity?
- Is there a significantly better way to build $G^k_\bot$ and $G^k_\top$ than first building weighted $G_\bot$ and $G_\top$ and then removing the edges of weight lower than $k$?

These questions are important in social network analysis and related fields. For instance, many studies consider co-authorship networks: $G$ is graph where authors are linked to papers, and $G^k_{\bot}$ is the graph of authors who co-signed at least $k$ papers.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

- The worst case of building $G_\top$ is in $\Omega(n^2)$ time and space: assume $\bot$ contains a single node linked to all nodes in $\top$.
- Maybe you are not looking for a worst case complexity? Then, $O(\sum_{u\in\bot}(d_u)^2)$ time to build $G_\top$ by listing all edges $u,v$ such that $u$ and $v$ are neighbors of the same node in $\bot$.
- You can use some pruning in the case $k$ is large with the following algorithm. For each node $u\in \top$ **such that its degree is $k$ or more**: For each neighbor $v$ of $u$: For each neighbor $w$ of $v$ such that $w>u$: List the edge $u,w$. Then postprocess the listed edges to find the ones that appear $k$ times or more. [Here](https://github.com/maxdan94/comcore) is a code that does something like that efficiently.
- Some related code [here](https://github.com/maxdan94/NeighSim) for simple graphs (not bipartite, but can be adapted) where we look for pairs of nodes with Jaccard similarity higher than a threshold. It seems that Jaccard allows to leverage a more aggressive pruning: only a pair of nodes $u,v$ such that $\frac{\min(d_u,d_v)}{\max(d_u,d_v)}>\alpha$ can have a Jaccard similarity higher than $\alpha$.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you! The $n^2$ bound is not what I am looking for, as the considered graphs are sparse; and the $\sum d^2$ is frustrating, as it may end up to be $n^2$, right? Your pruning methods are closer to what I am looking for, and maybe there is nothing better... It may lead to a complexity expressed in function of the input or output degree distribution, I think. Thanks for the implementation too! I add that your remark on the fact that other kinds of weights may be easier to compute is very interesting! This extends my question nicely!